# Which kind of video card can I mount on an AGP 8x slot?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, amd-radeon, agp

A Packard Bell PC with a [P5S800-VM motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5S800VM/) had a malfunction. After some investigation, it appeared to be caused by the [ATI Radeon 9550 video card](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/other/Pages/9550-overview.aspx).

Since it is not the first PC I used in which a malfunction is caused by an ATI video card, I would like to replace it with a video card from Nvidia or other brands.

Considering the motherboard and the constraint of the AGP 8X slot, what kind of graphics card can I mount? What specifications should I look for?

Comment: Welcome to the site! We're not doing specific shopping recommendations here, so I reworded (and generalized) your question just slightly, so it wouldn't become obsolete within a few months (i.e. when there are newer models of graphics cards around).

Comment: Thanks, from a SEO perspective your intervention is perfect :) From a user's perspective, more specificity is better, although it means reaching a minor audience (but more targeted). I specified the models because the only technical characteristics I gave are surely not enough to suggest a proper replacement. I agree with the deletion of the brand, I am open to any suggestion no matter what brand the video cards are.

Comment: Yeah, the point is that shopping recommendations are off-topic as you can read in the [FAQ], since they're very specialized – *and* we're not a forum, we're a Q&A site :) I would suggest to read [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) if you want to know more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy a NVidia GeForce 6600-6800, or ATI X-series, but your system is too old/slow to deal with any new AGP card (by new I mean more or less modern chip).

I have had this PC for 2 years a long time ago.

The major issues of that model are:

- SiS 661FX chipset used on its P5S800-VM mobo
- Pentium 4 519J CPU

both are bottle necks for a more powerful VGA

I've upgraded my PC with ASUS P5P800
http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5P800/

and Pentium 4 531 (with HT and extra 512 Kb of L2)
http://ark.intel.com/products/27465/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-531-supporting-HT-Technology-%281M-Cache-3_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB%29

after that I've noticed a performance leap, so I decided to buy an ATI X1950 Pro AGPx8
But even with new mobo and CPU, my VGA could not work at 100%.
DDR-1 is pretty slow (even if I oc'ed it from original 400 to 475 Mhz)

P.S. Buy a new cheap PC, even if it will be based on Intel Atom CPU you will gain in performance.

Comment: Thanks very much, I could not ask for a better answer! About the PC purpose, I am not looking for high video performances, I know it is an old model. It will be ok as a test-machine for sites and web apps or as a mini-server which does not turn off randomly each 8/10 hours.

Comment: As a server you would not even need to replace the card. Just run it headless and RDP in when you need to make changes.

Answer (score 2):

Any video card that will go in a AGP 8x slot should work.